# Adding XML Mapping excel files using PHPExcel

Tags: xml, mapping, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to export data from our database,
data retrieved from the database are formatted first before we write them to file. 
The output file type is ".xlsx".
Now, how can I attach XML Mappings to the headers of my excel files.

Here's the scenario,

I retrieve data from our database, 
then loop each data for writing.

Now, the client asked me to add XML mapping to my files, since there system doesn't accept excel files without the mapping.

Thank you in advance.!

PS: please be good to me since I am a newbie to this..
Thank you so much!!

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean... do you want to actually change the structure of the xml files that comprise the xlsx?

Comment: Hello @MarkBaker, I actually want to attach xml information to my cells before I write them to my output .xlsx files

Comment: Do you simply mean XML content? That's just a string value, surely

Comment: So, can I just use something like this:  $xls->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue("D3","<data>Account No.</data>");

Comment: That's perfectly valid code; and it'll store that string in the cell... if it needs to be anything more than a simple string value, then you'll need to explain exactly what you mean

Comment: I'm already thinking of using a xml schema file for this, so how can I do that??

Comment: I still don't understand what you want. What do you need an XML Schema for in a spreadsheet? Excel doesn't recognise XML content in cells as anything other than a string, so just store a string in each cell